# How to fix Facebook URL loaded error

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, hybridauth

I am using [Hybridauth](https://hybridauth.github.io/) library in my application to make user logged in through Facebook. I am getting the error below

> Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

I am unable to solve it. I am unable to find the right error. Please help me out. Below are the app settings screenshots
[App basic setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJqIc.png)

[Product setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVP3y.png)

**Here is the error screenshot**
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnTUT.png)

Comment: Making up our mind as to whether your domain is spelled `coogos` or `ccogos` seems like an ideal starting point to me in this specific instance.

Comment: I had already updated this spell mistake but forgot to update the screenshot. Now I've updated the screenshot too. Error is still same.

Comment: Solution is also still the same as in the _countless_ other discussions on this over the last few weeks - specify the correct redirect URI(s), with the exact same value the parameter has in the actual login dialog call. Check what that actually is in the browser address bar, when the login dialog is shown.

Comment: Please check error screenshot I have added yet.

Comment: Now that can't be the truth either, if you had really just called `https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth` with no parameters whatsoever, it should give you `The parameter app_id is required` ...

Comment: This was working some days ago but stop working now unexpectedly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49570837/how-to-fix-facebook-url-loaded-error?noredirect=1#comment86220191_49570837

Comment: Please help me where i am wrong.

Comment: Did you do what I asked you to do? What was the result?

Comment: What type of redirect URL must be?

Comment: What do you mean, "type"? Again: It needs to be the exact same value the redirect_uri parameter actually has in the login dialog call.

Comment: @CBroe thank you for help. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You must read this article first to solve this issue. [How to fix Facebook apps “Error: Can’t Load URL: The domain of this URL isn’t included in the app’s domains”](https://wp-native-articles.com/blog/news/how-to-fix-facebook-apps-error-cant-load-url-domain-url-isnt-included-apps-domains/)

I read it and found out that i am missing something in redirect_uri. I was missing some parameter(s) in redirect_uri.

**How I solved it?**

- I checked the URL where above error was comming. Look at the URL `www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth?auth_type=rerequest&client_id=111111111&state=e5d6b215cb999as5efc7cd18d34890b9&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.6.2&redirect_uri=www.domain.com/fbcallback?hauth_done= Facebook&scope=email,public_profile,user_friends`

Look at the parameter in the URL **redirect_url** i-e `www.domain.com/fbcallback?hauth_done=Facebook`. In your app settings, *your Valid OAuth Redirect URIs* must be look like above as i mentioned earlier.
Must be like

```
www.domain.com/fbcallback?hauth_done=Facebook
```

It works for me flawlessly. :-)